# Simple Captcha - How to test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am using Simple Captcha plugin for generating the captcha. Does anybody know how do I modify rails tests to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Simple Captcha automatically returns that the captcha is valid if the RAILS_ENV is "test". From the source code:

```
def simple_captcha_valid?
  return true if RAILS_ENV == 'test'
...
```